# How can I detect orphaned objects in S3 that aren't mapped to our database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to find possible orphans in an S3 bucket. What I mean is that we might delete something out of the DB, and for whatever reason, it doesn't get cleared from S3. This can be a bug in our system or something of that nature. I want to double check against our API that the object in S3 maps to something that exists - the naming convention let's us map things together like that.

Scraping an entire bucket every X days seems unscalable. I was thinking that for each object in the bucket, it can add itself to an SQS queue for the relevant checking to happen, every 30 days or so.

I've only found events around uploads and specific modifications over at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html. Is there anything more generalized I can't find? Any creative solutions to this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "orphans" in a bucket?

Comment: I will clarify in question!

Comment: Get an S3 Inventory and query your API for each listed object.

Comment: @jarmod You might want to write an answer with some details so I can reward something. I almost thought you were suggesting querying like I said I don't want to do but I googled and see "You can configure what object metadata to include in the inventory, whether to list all object versions or only current versions, where to store the inventory list file output, and whether to generate the inventory on a daily or weekly basis"

Comment: On second thought - is it possible for the inventory to generate events based on the creation date? If not, that is almost identical to what I said above about scraping the entire bucket all the time. Even if I am scraping every 30 days... that is all of them at once through some long loop to add to SQS

Comment: Listing an S3 bucket is not a trivial task if you have millions or billions of objects. The S3 Inventory report is the best way to do this. S3 event triggers probably won't help you because they don't happen when your app fails to be prompted to delete an object from S3. One option might be to change your deletion process to "write S3 key to DynamoDB, delete object from S3, remove key from DynamoDB". Then run a reaper process once per day to list items in the DynamoDB table and forcefully delete any objects whose keys are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should activate [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a regular CSV file (as often as daily) that contains a list of every object in the Amazon S3 bucket.

You could then trigger some code that compares the contents of the CSV file against the database to find 'orphan' objects.